# Convert columns into a single row in notepad++

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

I want to make .srt file for the subtitles. for that i had the text in excel file. I copied the text into notepad++. Below is the text i have, and under that the formatting i want for the .srt file. I am not very fluent in notepad++. can anyone help me

the data I have:
[image: excel screenshot of the data]

data pasted in notepad++:
[image: Notepad++ screenshot of data]

the output I want:
[image: notepad screenshot of data]

data to copy paste

```
1   00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:05,000   Hello,
2   00:00:05,000 --> 00:00:17,000   My name is John
3   00:00:20,000 --> 00:00:32,000   I'm from USA
4   00:00:34,000 --> 00:00:46,000   I work in a coffee shop
5   00:00:49,000 --> 00:00:57,000   which is very far from my home.
```

Comment: Your title doesn't meet your question!

Answer (score 2):

The right-arrow you see is a tab, so it looks to me like you want to replace tab with new line. You can do this with regex using the parameters in the image below

[image]

This changes

[image]

into

[image]